# How to test a web page from my local machine after it is loaded in my browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jestjs, mocha.js

I have a website that is running on some server, which is used by a few thousand people. It's built on Java and soy template. I need to test the fronted rendering/js files. Can I do this from my local machine after accessing the web page?

for example: say I need to run a few Javascript test files on facebook.com. I go to facebook.com in my browser, after it is loaded, I need to run a few js files to test it. Is it possible? if yes, should I use Mocha or jest or any other alternate framework?

Answer (score 1):

Only you can do is `E2E` testing. `E2E` testing is an UI automation testing. Here are the `e2e` testing framework choices:

- [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)
- [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/)
- [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/)
- [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/)

You can [use jestjs with puppeteer](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer).

Comment: Thank you so much. Will work on these and see which one will fit the best.

Answer (score 0):

There are different test types that can be run against code: [Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), [Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing), [Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing), etc. Some types have different test methodologies: [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development), etc. In this instance it seems you are wanting Functional Tests usually using the BDD method. In regard to your post, you state Java but tag the post Javascript and mention the Mocha framework. I'm assuming you meant Javascript instead of Java, with that said Mocha does support Functional Tests:

https://mochajs.org/#retry-tests

You will need the [Selenium Driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) to be installed along with other specific web browser drivers: Chrome, Edge, Gecko. A quick search shows that there might be an easier path to get up and running:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-webdriver

I have no experience with that library but leave further investigation up to you.